# my form page populated with previously submitted data

Tags: html

I filled the form page and submitted it.again when I opened the form page to generate another request my form page populated with previously submitted data.How can I get the form page with empty values.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can try following to avoid the prepopulated values in form

1. use ctrl+F5 to refresh the page.
2. reload the page by pasting the URL in address bar and press enter
3. you can also include javascript that will clear the form fields when the page loads

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<form autocomplete="off">`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12341149)

Comment: This is the answer to the question, this is what user is missing in the code